# Creating a POJO model from a JSON with an array

Tags: java, json, spring

I am trying to create a java model for a JSON structure that looks like this:

```
"notification": {
      "field": "string",           
      "object": [
      {
        "field2": "string",
        "object2": [
          {
            "field3": "string",
            "object3": {
              "code": "string",
              "proprietary": "string"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
 }
```

So far my model looks like this:

```
public class Notification {

      private String field = "sample value";
      public List<object> sampleObject= new ArrayList<object>();

        public String getField() {
            return field;
        }

        public void setField(String notifyingParticipantfinancialInstitutionBIC) {
            this.field = field;
        }

        public List<object> getObject() {
            return object;
        }

        public void setObject(List<object> sampleObject) {
            this.sampleObject = sampleObject;
        }
    }
    
    public class object{

        public String field2 = "string";
        public List<object2> sampleObject2 = null;

        public String getField2() {
            return field2;
        }

        public void setField2(String field2) {
            this.field2 = field2;
        }

        public List<object2> getObject2() {
            return object2;
        }

        public void setObject2(List<object2> sampleObject2) {
            this.object2 = object2;
        }
    }
```

I have populated some of the existing fields just to make sure I can print back a json from this POJO model. When I print it using:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            Notification test = new Notification();
            String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(test);
```

i get this JSON object:

```
"notification": {
        "field": "string",
        "object": []
    }
```

What am I doing wrong with my 1st object class? I'm not sure why the List is not populating all the other nested variables and objects within it, but returning an empty array.

////

Just fixed it thanks to pleft and Nagaraju Chitimilla's correction! I had to add the new objects to my main object.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add some objects in your list!

e.g.

```
Notification test = new Notification();
test.getObject().add(new object()); //Add a new object in your object list
```

Comment: This works! Yes you're right, i forgot to add the object in. Now the other nested objects should work too. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you created and added object and object2?

e.g.

```
 Notification test = new Notification();
object obj =new object();
List list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(obj);
test.setObject(list);
```

Comment: Yes you're right! I forgot to add the objects to my list. Thank you so much!!